# Triple integration for surface area

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to find the surface area of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=10^2$ above the cone $z=
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

I need to use the formula $$\int \int \int _E \sqrt{f_x (x,y,z)^2+f_y(x,y,z)^2+f_z(x,y,z)^2+1}\ DA$$
in terms of spherical coordinates. So my attempt of setting this up was $$\int \int \int _E \sqrt{4(x^2+y^2+z^2)+1}DA \\ = \int \int \int _E\sqrt{4p^2 +1}\ p^2\sin\phi \ dp d\theta d\phi$$
where $$0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi \\ 0\leq p \leq 10 \\ 0\leq \phi \leq \pi/4$$
but I'm still not getting the right answer. I think my bounds are incorrect or maybe the integrand itself is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are to find surface area of the part of the sphere and hence $\rho = 10$.

The surface area element in spherical coordinates is given by $ \rho^2 \sin \phi ~ d\phi ~ d\theta$

So the answer should be,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/4} 10^2 \sin \phi ~ d\phi ~ d\theta = 100 (2 - \sqrt2) \pi$

---

To see why surface area element is $\rho^2 \sin \phi$, parametrize the surface of the sphere as,

$r(\phi, \theta) = (\rho \cos\theta \sin \phi, \rho \sin\theta \sin\phi, \rho \cos\phi)$

Now taking partial derivative wrt $\phi$ and $\theta$ and then finding $|r_{\phi} \times r_{\theta}|$, you will get $\rho^2 \sin\phi$

Comment: This worked! but I'm not understanding why that function gives surface area. Do you have a source that explains it well so i can check it out?

Comment: I just added something. pls check.